# Expect/Tcl: 'string map' removing content in string?

Tags: string, tcl, expect

**SETUP:** Expect/Tcl Script in Linux

**USE CASE:**

Using `expect` to wait for the report of some status to be used in a `$user_command`.

```
expect  -re "notify (.+)\n"  
set     status $expect_out(1,string)
send   [string map [list SESSION "$status"] "$user_command"]
```

So when the application sends "`notify running`", then `status` is set to `running`.
For that a keyword `STATUS` in `$user_command` needs to be replaced with `$status`, such that, for example

```
"log STATUS to file"
```

becomes

```
"log running to file"
```

To see what is happing, I wrote

```
expect_tty  -re "(.+)\n"  
set         status $expect_out(1,string)
send_user   [string map [list SESSION "$status"] "$user_command"]
```

which works fine when running isolatedly. The output is

```
log someUserInput to file
```

when typing `someUserInput` to responde to `expect_tty`. However, as part of a larger script, the string map command it removes anything before the string replacement, so that the output becomes

```
" to file"
```

(without a newline) I checked for the uniqueness of variables in the script, so that this is not an issue.

**QUESTION:**

What is going on here? How can I make the script robust?

Comment: Try to come up with a reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Be aware that expect always uses `\r\n` line endings. `$status` will contain `running\r` here which would explain the unexpected output.

Comment: @glenn technically speaking it's not Expect who "always uses" `\r\n`s. it's the pty's usual (not always) behaviors. Expect itself does not care what it gets from the pty.

Comment: @glennjackman: Please, make this an answer, so I can checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @glennjackman:

The problem is due to applications reporting newline as `\r\n`, so that `(.*)\n` in

```
expect_tty  -re "(.+)\n"
```

matches in expression 1 (the thing inside the brackets) something that includes `\r` at the end. With `\r` removing anything before it, `string map` seems to cut anything before the replaced string. The solution is to expect something that excludes `\r`, i.e.

```
expect -re ``(\[^\r\n\]+)``
```

which collects anything until end of line, whatsoever the format may be.

Answer (score 1):

The `string map` command is *exactly* deterministic. At each character of its input string, in order, it considers whether any of the *from* strings in the mapping list match, in order, and if so it performs the replacement (with the paired *to* string) and goes on to consider the character immediately after the replaced substring. (The empty string is a special case: it's *never* matched.) The code to implement it is really quite stupid, but happens to be very cache friendly on modern computers so it's still very fast; more sophisticated and supposedly “faster” implementations have been tried, but found to be slower in practice with the kinds of maps usually encountered in the wild.

If the replacement is failing to apply, it's usually because the input string is not quite what you expect. In most programs this is rare, but it's more common with expect programs because the output of the terminal emulation engine inside them can include metacharacters for things like moving the cursor around and changing the color. (Often the easiest fix for that is to tell the spawned program that its terminal type is one that doesn't support such complex features, perhaps by setting the `TERM` environment variable to `dumb`.)